# php post data using curl

Tags: php, curl

When I post the data using ajax and send to `post.php` by curl then `$_FILES` variable is empty and get the data in `$_POST` variable. When I print `$_POST` var getting the following data on `post.php`.

```
   [temp_upload_file] => @/tmp/php6OHgQc;filename=Penguins.jpg;type=image/jpeg
```

when I print "$_FILES" var getting empty data on post.php

```
Array
(
)
```

Code:

```
$url = "post.php";
$ch = curl_init($url);
// send a file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array('temp_upload_file' =>'@'.$_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'].';filename='.$_FILES['uploadfile']['name'].';type='. $_FILES['uploadfile']['type']);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
// output the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: multipart/form-data'));
echo curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

What I am doing wrong here??

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

For php5.5+ there is a new curl_file_create() function you need to use
the @ format is now deprecated.

Try using following code:

```
$url = "post.php";
$tmpfile = $_FILES['temp_upload_file']['tmp_name'];
$filename = basename($_FILES['temp_upload_file']['name']);

$ch = curl_init($url);
// send a file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
    'uploaded_file' => curl_file_create($tmpfile, $_FILES['uploadfile']['type'], $filename)
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
// output the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: multipart/form-data'));
echo curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```